DIY Boat material
I have alot of thick HDPE liner lying around and i thinking using it for a small boat project.
Is it possible to build a frame out of plywood and cover it with single sheet of HDPE liner for water proofing?
What could be the drawbacks of such a method?

Search for "skin on frame boat", it should give you some pointer

You can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coracle for inspiration, those are boats build from a frame and a sheet of fabric.
